# JSON to arrays Python

Tags: python, json

I searched on internet, without success, a way to set JSON infos into arrays, with a JSON file like:

```
{ "_links": {}, "chatter_count": 3, "chatters": { "moderators": ["nightbot", "mistercraft"], "staff": [], "admins": [], "global_mods": [], "viewers": [] } }
```

And in the code, when I put for example

```
Print(moderators)
```

Or

```
Print(*Filename*.moderators())
```

And the code show me `["nightbot", "mistercraft"]`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the good way to convert a Json file to python variable:

```
import json

data = None
with open('/path/to/your/file/here.json', 'r') as fd:
    data = json.loads(fd.read())
print data["chatters"]["moderators"]
```

Here what the code is doing:

The code below open the file from the given path, read all the content and convert it into a dict() object which is a python default type (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

You can also parse json directly from a string:

```
import json

json_str = '{ "_links": {}, "chatter_count": 3, "chatters": { "moderators": ["nightbot", "mistercraft"], "staff": [], "admins": [], "global_mods": [], "viewers": [] } }'
data = json.loads(json_str)
print data["chatters"]["moderators"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built-in [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) for this. The `json.loads` method will return a `dict` object in your case.

```
>>> import json

>>> json_data = json.loads('{ "_links": {}, "chatter_count": 3, "chatters": { "moderators": ["nightbot", "mistercraft"], "staff": [], "admins": [], "global_mods": [], "viewers": [] } }')
>>> json_data
{u'chatters': {u'moderators': [u'nightbot', u'mistercraft'], u'global_mods': [], u'admins': [], u'viewers': [], u'staff': []}, u'_links': {}, u'chatter_count': 3}

>>> json_data['chatters']['moderators']
[u'nightbot', u'mistercraft']
```

If you are dealing with a json file instead of json string, then you should use the `json.load` method instead of `json.loads`, like below -

```
with open('path/to/json/file') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from json import loads
array = loads('{ "_links": {}, "chatter_count": 3, "chatters": { "moderators": ["nightbot", "mistercraft"], "staff": [], "admins": [], "global_mods": [], "viewers": [] } }')
```

Then you can access "moderators" like this:

```
array["chatters"]["moderators"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the JSON library: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

To parse your JSON:

```
import json
json.loads(json_text)
```

From your example, this would return a dict.

To access your moderators:

```
import json

chatter=json.loads(json_text)
moderators = chatter.get('chatters',{}).get('moderators')
```

moderators will now be the array `["nightbot", "mistercraft"]`

Comment: json.dumps do not parse anything, you are mistaking it with json.loads / json.load

Comment: @lelabo_m yes, I am. Fixing